# What's the Ack number of the packets sent in CLOSE-WAIT state?

Tags: networking, tcp, rfc

I read in my network textbook that in a TCP communication between host A and host B, if A sends an `FIN` to B, B will send an `ACK` back to A (suppose the `Ack number` of this packet is **x**) and enter the `CLOSE-WAIT` state. Then, B may still want to send some data to A. If not, B will right away sends back an `FIN` to A. **No matter which case, the `Ack number` of this `FIN` sent by B should also be x.**

My question is: **When B is sending data in `CLOSE-WAIT` state, will it still receive `ACK` from A? If so, considering that the `Ack number` of the `FIN` to be sent by B should also be x, what will the `SEQ` of these `ACK` sent by A be? In other words, what will the `Ack number` of the packets sent by B in `CLOASE-WAIT` state be? Are all of them also x? If not, how could B know whether A has received the data or not?**

I tried to search `CLOSE-WAIT send data` and something like this on Google but didn't find anything about this. And I also tried to search `CLOSE-WAIT` in RFC 793 but still didn't find anything about this question while browsing. It seems that I didn't use the correct keywords for retrieval.

I would be very grateful if you could attach the related contents in the RFC.

Comment: The Acknowledgement Number is always the next expected Sequence Number. With the ACK flag, it means that it acknowledges everything _prior_ to the Acknowledgement Number, and tells the other side what data it expects next.

Comment: @RonMaupin So, do you mean that the Acknowledgement Number of the FIN sent by B is not requeired to be x?

Comment: You should read _[RFC 793, Transmission Control Protocol](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc793)_, which is the definition of TCP. It explains the Acknowledgement number: "_If the ACK control bit is set this field contains the value of the next sequence number the sender of the segment is expecting to receive. Once a connection is established this is always sent._"